# NNO = (first order) PA

Tags: peano-arithmetic, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

Recall the definition of a [Natural Numbers Object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object) in a topos, and the [first order axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano%27s_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) for Peano Arithmetic. I am more familiar with the first definition than the second, so I cannot tell from the (obviously infallible) Wikipedia page whether first order PA is equivalent to 'second order' PA -- PA with the induction axiom scheme replaced by a similar one involving inductive subsets $A \subset \mathbb{N}$.

The equivalence between 'second order' PA and a NNO in $Set$ in one direction (NNO $\Rightarrow$ PA) is easy, and the other (PA $\Rightarrow$ NNO) is in MacLane's book *Mathematics, form and function* which I haven't seen (bonus question: another reference for the proof would be nice).

But I would like to see a proof of NNO = (first order) PA, if possible.

My motivation is to consider possibly weaker forms of arithmetic, and it is how to deal with (versions of) the induction axiom schema as usually presented from a logic point of view on which I would like a bit of background.

Edit: As Andreas points out, I really should be asking about *models* of PA and NNOs.

Comment: As it stands, the question asks about equivalence between a structure (an NNO) and a theory (PA).  Please clarify what you mean by that. 

Comment: Mac Lane's book is available for download here: http://libgen.info/view.php?id=268190

Comment: @Andreas - you're absolutely right. I'm editing the question to make it better-formed.

Answer (score 7):

J. Lambek and P. J. Scott: Introduction to higher-order categorical logic, Cambridge University Press, 1986, Part II, Section 4, [Theorem 4.1](http://books.google.si/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&f=false) shows that a nno satisfies the first-order Peano rules (which are listed on [page 135](http://books.google.si/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&f=false) under 3.7, 3.8., 3.9), while Part II, Section 12, [Proposition 12.4](http://books.google.si/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q=lambek%2520scott%2520higher-order%2520categorical%2520logic&f=false) shows that Peano rules give a nno for the syntactic topos. By the universal property of the syntactic topos it then follows that in any topos which validates Peano rules has a nno.

The whole business with classical vs. non-classical logic is a red herring. You may throw excluded middle in if that is your wish.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. I knew the internal logic of the topos would have to make an entrance at some point, because we can't always work in $Set$.

Comment: You can apply the results just to $\mathrm{Set}$ if you wish. That is a special case.

Comment: So I presume (because I can't read all the details in Lambek-Scott via Google Books) that one could have a model of the Peano axioms in a topos, but the NNO is not necessarily isomorphic to it?

Comment: Andrej, aren't these results about higher-order type theories with power types and full comprehension? They say that a topos with NNO is equivalent to a model of higher-order type theory with full comprehension, in the sense that you can go back and forth (using internal language and syntactic category). Since full comprehension is always assumed, this says little about first-order PA.

Comment: @Ulrik: I am not sure I understand your objection. The question asked for a proof that in a topos the nno satisfies the Peano axioms, and that an object in a topos satisfying the Peano axioms is a NNO. Surely then, in proving these things we can work with anything that the topos provides. The "first-order" in the question does not refer to the ambient logic (which you correctly observe to be higher-order), but to the first-order Peano axioms (as opposed to some higher-order version), in particular induction is stated as a schema. Do I make sense?

Comment: @Andrej: yes, you make sense, and I guess my objection is more terminological: I would take first-order PA to satisfy an induction schema for first-order formulas only, whereas the version here (in Lambek and Scott) is schematic in all (ambiently definable) predicates on N. If you have a PA object N in a topos that only satisfies induction for first-order formulas, then it could be non-standard, but in the topos logic you could then separate out the standard part and make a NNO. 

Comment: @Ulrik: That is a good observation, I did not understand what you were saying. And reading Lambek & Scott it is clear that they apply induction not to a formula but to a subobject generated in a rather impredicative way. No surprise there, now that you pointed it out.

Answer (score 5):

A NNO is unique up to isomorphism (likewise, a model of second-order arithmetic is unique). In contrast, every first-order theory with at least one infinite model has a proper class of nonisomorphic models of arbitrary large cardinalities, due to Löwenheim–Skolem theorem. Thus, NNO cannot be equivalent to PA, or any other first-order arithmetic for that matter.

Comment: There is something more subtle here. Category theory, after all, is a first-order theory, and so while within each topos with a NNO the NNO is unique, of course this doesn't mean the NNOs between different categories must be isomorphic (for example, consider the NNOs in SET in a countable $\omega$-model of ZFC and a countable non-$\omega$-model of ZFC).  I think the interesting question is: given some "standard" axiomatization $TN$ for a topos with a NNO, let $ATN$ be the set of sentences of arithmetic provable from $TN$. How does $ATN$ compare with $PA$? N.B. this is a syntactic question. 

Comment: In other words, a question I don't know the answer to, because of a lack of familiarity with topos theory, is whether a 'standard' axiomatization of $ATN$ proves the entire theory $Z_2$ of classical second-order arithmetic. I suspect the answer is "yes" from things I have heard, at least if we are talking about toposes with classical internal logic, but in any case I think that this syntactic question gets to the heart of the matter. 

Comment: But this does not seem to be the question the OP is interested in, as he equates NNO with second-order arithmetic (the real categorical one, not two-sorted first-order arithmetic like $Z_2$), and the only way to make sense of that he means models of the arithmetical theory inside the topos. Your question is interesting, but a different one. As for an answer, first, a trivial topos is a topos with a NNO, hence ATN does not even prove $0\ne1$. Ignoring that, the elementary theory of the category of sets (topos with NNO, well-pointed, all epis split) is supposed to have the same strength as ...

Comment: ... Zermelo's set theory with separation restricted to $\Delta_0$-formulas. I believe this theory should prove that Z_2 holds in the standard model, since all relevant quantifiers are bounded to $\omega$ or $\mathcal P(\omega)$. The theory should prove much more arithmetic than that (due to its richer language), and in particular, I guess it proves the consistency of $Z_2$. I have no idea what happens when you drop the well-pointedness axiom and the axiom of choice.

Comment: (Zermelo's set theory is ZFC without replacement and foundation.)

Comment: Is the original question just saying that ZFC proves that the NNO of Set interprets PA in the model-theoretic sense? If that is the case, we can say more: ZFC proves that the NNO of Set interprets the entire first-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ - this is just a consequence of the usual ZFC proof of categoricity of Peano arithmetic with full set induction. The only way that we would be able to limit what can be interpreted into models of NNO would be to look at nonstandard models, but then we get back to variants of my question where we look at various axioms for the topos. 

Comment: I think you are confused by the terminology. The original question says that NNO is a model of *second* *order* Peano arithmetic (i.e., the original categorical [as in having only one model] Peano axioms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms , this is not what logicians are used to call Peano arithmetic these days), and conversely, that any model of second-order Peano arithmetic gives rise to a NNO. In other words, NNO is just a categorical [as in category theory] way of describing the standard model of arithmetic.

Comment: I agree the issue is in the terminology of the question.  It comes down to which collection of NNOs is being considered. If the original question is just saying that within any model $M$ of set theory, the particular NNO from the category $Set^M$ is isomorphic to $\omega^M$, that's fine. But if an arbitrary NNO does not satisfy $0 \not = 1$ then it can't be a model of any sort of Peano arithmetic. And a nontrivial NNO in a topos that has a nonclassical logic cannot possibly verify all the classical logical validities, so its theory could not possibly be true second-order arithmetic, right? 

Comment: I would assume that a nonclassical topos does not think that true second-order arithmetic is classical. I don't know whether it makes sense in an intuitionistic topos to talk about satisfaction of formulas in a model at all, but if so, then the most natural way (and I don't know any other way) of *defining* true second-order arithmetic is as the sentences valid in the standard model of arithmetic, i.e., in the NNO, so the topos thinks the theory of the NNO is the true second-order arithmetic pretty much by definition. I guess it will also know the theory can be "axiomatized" by  ...

Comment: ... the (second-order) Peano axioms in what it thinks is the second-order logic (which will not be classical). I'm not sure what happens in the trivial topos, but my guess is that the internal logic of the topos is then inconsistent anyway.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Emil. I had a look at MacLane and he makes similar comments regarding first order vs second order. I'm editing the question.

Comment: @David Roberts: I am very suspicious of your claims to Carl. Are you quite sure that $\mathrm{Sub}(N)$ is Boolean in a sheaf topos? Wouldn't that imply that $\mathrm{Sub}(1)$ is Boolean? Also, why is the constant $\mathbb{N}$-valued sheaf the nno in a sheaf topos? I thought you had to sheafify it, so you typically get something like the sheaf of locally constant $\mathbb{N}$-valued maps.

Comment: @Andrej: ah, I forgot that $N$ might have subobjects other than $\sum_{n\in A \subset \mathbb{N}} 1$ - you are right about the implication about $Sub(1)$. And of course, the nno in a sheaf topos is the sheafification of the constant sheaf.

Comment: @David: The unique object of a trivial topos (which is also the terminal object) together with the identity map is a NNO, directly from the definition. It does satisfy $N\simeq N\coprod1$, since in the trivial topos, its unique object is a limit and a colimit of any diagram.

Comment: Well, I am going to delete my 'suspicious claims' then. Thanks for the corrections Andrej and Emil!